# How to run black/isort on check-only mode for vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lint, python-black

I could not find the way how to run black/isort on "read-only" mode, i.e., `--check/--check-only` flag on VSCode.
There was "format on save" option, but I prefer "check where is wrong line and run formatter manually" way.
(That is, I want to use black/isort as **linter** instead of **formatter** in vscode)

Is there any option to do this? Or, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Both [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html?#diffs) and [isort](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#show-diff) have a `--diff` flag that outputs the changes that would have been made in the files without actually changing them. From black docs (isort usage is similar):

```
$ black test.py --diff
--- test.py     2021-03-08 22:23:40.848954 +0000
+++ test.py     2021-03-08 22:23:47.126319 +0000
@@ -1 +1 @@
-print ( 'hello, world' )
+print("hello, world")
would reformat test.py
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file would be reformatted.
```

I don't know how to integrate this output with VSCode's editor, but it's a start for what you're looking for.